# Swift : How can i obtain a documented value for UIImagePickerControllerMediaType

Tags: ios, swift

Currently to know what is media type i obtain "public.image" if user select image into camera roll or take a new picture and "public.movie" if is a movie.

I read Apple documentation for UIImagePickerControllerMediaType and i see this :

```
let UIImagePickerControllerMediaType: String
```

Constants

```
UIImagePickerControllerMediaType

Specifies the media type selected by the user.

The value for this key is an NSString object containing a type code such as kUTTypeImage or kUTTypeMovie.
```

This is my code :

```
    let mediaType:String = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! String


    if mediaType == "public.image" {
        ....

    } else if mediaType == "public.movie" {
        ....
    }
```

How can i compare mediaType with official documentation values (kUTTypeImage or kUTTypeMovie) ?

Comment: You mean like `mediaType == String(kUTTypeImage)` ?

Comment: It's working ! Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mediaType == String(kUTTypeImage)